# Can I create triggers on system views in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Can I create triggers on views in the `sys` schema in SQL Server?

When I tried to right click on Triggers and clicked on New Trigger... on `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` view it gives me the below error in SQL Server 2008 R2:

> "The object 'sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats' does not exist or is invalid
>   for this operation."

Comment: Why do you want to create triggers on sys views

Comment: No, you cannot. They'd be pretty pointless anyway, since the views are not designed to be updatable (so nothing should be executing DML operations against them)

Comment: presumably you were hoping to run some code when an event happens that changes some of the data that this view returns? What exactly are you trying to do? There may be some alternative depending on what exactly you are trying to monitor.

Comment: Yes, that's what exactly I want Martin Smith.I want to track stored procedures used in my database and one alternative I know is to create job with this query:    SELECT p.name AS 'SP Name'        -- Get list of all SPs in the current database
    FROM sys.procedures AS p
    WHERE p.is_ms_shipped = 0

    EXCEPT

    SELECT p.name AS 'SP Name'        -- Get list of all SPs from the current database 
    FROM sys.procedures AS p          -- that are in the procedure cache
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS qs
    ON p.object_id = qs.object_id
    WHERE p.is_ms_shipped = 0;

Comment: @MartinSmith Any alternatives to this? I'm fighting the same problem (although my goal is different) and I'm pretty sure it's not the best option.